# ServiceStack Timeout - ASP.NET executionTimeout

Tags: asp.net, timeout, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack's JsonServiceClient but I've seen that despite setting the client timeout, the HTTP call still goes wrong after a certain period of time. I fixed this by setting the executionTimeout parameter of ASP.NET. What is the difference between these two timeouts given that the ServiceStack client should be a wrapper of that of the framework?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Timeout` property configures the `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` property but it depends on which .NET runtime you're running on as the implementation of .NET's `HttpWebRequest` was completely rewritten to use `HttpClient` in .NET Core.

If you're on .NET 6+ it's recommended to use the [JsonApiClient](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client.html#jsonapiclient) otherwise all previous .NET Core Apps should use `JsonHttpClient` whilst .NET Framework Apps can use either `JsonServiceClient` or `JsonHttpClient`.

Comment: So it's not enough for me so set the timeout of HttpWebRequest.Timeout? Being both objects proposed by the framework I thought that setting the client timeout automatically the override of that of ASP.NET. I’m using .NET Framework

Comment: Try also setting `ReadWriteTimeout`

Comment: Ok, I’ll try it